# "Format is not recognized" error while trying to sign xap-file with signtool

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, signtool

I am trying to follow this tutotial:
http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/Overview/Overview/Moving-Beyond-the-Browser--Elevated-Trust-Applications/#_Toc256192962
in order to sign my silverlight application.

But on the last step which is something like that:

signtool sign /v /f c:\Demo\TestOOBCodeSigningCA.pfx /p password c:\Demo\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2.Web\ClientBin\SilverlightApplication2.xap

I got the following error:

SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized
SignTool Error: An error occured while attempting to sign: c:\Demo\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2.Web\ClientBin\SilverlightApplication2.xap

What can be the reason?

Comment: You are using the Silveright 4 RC?  What is the path to the signtool.exe?

Comment: I am using Silverlight 4 Beta. That must be the reason! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must install the Silverlight 4 runtime on the signing machine. If you have only installed the SL 3 runtime so you will receive the error "This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized"